# Water in Ark: Survival Evolved is rendered flat and gray

Tags: linux, ark-survival-evolved

Running on Linux Mint 18.1 Cinnamon with Nvidia graphics Card 16 gb of ram (more specific info will follow upon request if necessary)

I haven't made any changes to hardware, software, etc. This is an occurence within the last day which until a few minutes ago, was accompanied by a sky which had huge white blocks swirl around like racing space debris.

I fixed the sky (and I'd hoped the water too) by uninstalling Ark and reinstalling. I validated the files before and after multiple times. I don't understand why this problem has started to occur. With 180 hours, this is definitely a first for me. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a bug that is happening with all linux and mac OS.

EDIT:

Ark devs have acknowledged the issue and even better, A workaround has been found by user Loki42 on the survivetheark forum. 
He copied the center water depth file over to the island location and solved the problem. Note that you need to have the center map installed on your machine for this to work.
Please visit the link and give him positive feedback if at all possible.

Here is the link:
https://survivetheark.com/index.php?/forums/topic/210557-v261-grey-water-surface/&do=findComment&comment=1476164